# Which code is running UI that I currently see

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I started to work on existing app with complete source, currently compiled and run from eclipse.

I start the app for debugging and interact with it on my device.

Is there a way to know what Activity/Fragment source code is executing for what I currently see on my device's screen ?

Comment: you can insert log statements, in each activity and then observe the log cat.

Comment: You can use Android Device Monitor for check layout hierarchy.

Comment: Create a Toast Message in your current activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a very simple solution.

Just put a breakpoint in framework's `Activity#onCreate` or `Fragment#onCreate`.

It will stop there every time your custom Activity/Fragment is on screen, since all your Fragments/Activities are calling `super.onCreate()` on startup.

At this breakpoint debugger will show you actual value of `this`, which gives you name of "MyCustomFragment" class you see on screen.

Prerequisite for this is attaching android sources for debugging - find many answers on SO how to do it with AS, if you don't do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could check if there are logging statements that could point you to the right direction.
2. If the code is really chaotic and you can't find you way around it, one really non-optimal option is to look for some unique resource strings that appear on the activity and then try and trace them back to the source code.
3. On eclipse debug view (Window -> open perspective -> Debug), there is a suspend button (looks like a pause button) which displays the current call stack. It might also be of some help.